# Can I use native browser apis in crossrider extensions e.g gBrowser for chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crossrider

so am developing an extension using crossrider and want to use native browser APIs after detecting which browser the extension is working from, am experiencing a bug that only the native APIs can solve it.

Comment: "gBrowser" is a meaningless concept in the context of Google Chrome extensions. Are you referring to gBrowser in Firefox add-ons?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use browser specific APIs for which the extension has permissions and use our [appAPI.browser.name](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browser-property-name) and [appAPI.browser.version](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browser-property-version) properties to differentiate between browsers.

However, if you are experiencing a specific problem with a Crossrider API method, please email support@crossrider.com with the details and we will be happy to assist you.

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: After moving project to production, then downloading it, it failed to work, all of the browser extensions, yet in staging and debugging mode it was working great

Comment: Please can you provide the extension id and I will be happy to investigate. If you prefer to keep this private, please email the details to support@crossrider.com. [Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Its okay, I was able to solve it...thanks for the help thoug, you guys are doing a great job in stackoverflow